# Are there cases where Android would start an app/service other than due to Intents or explicit user start?

Tags: launcher, task-management, multitasking, processes

I'm trying to understand how/why some of the processes that are running on my phone (DroidX, stock 2.2 ROM).

It's obvious that 2 likely reasons for a process to start are:

- A direct action by the user/another program to start it (e.g. click on the icon of an app, or another process launches the .apk explicitly)
- An [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) is registered by the app, and the event associated with that intent happens.

**The question is, are there other reasons/causes/mechanisms by which a process could be started in Android?** (**aside from Intents** or direct launch).

P.S. As a plausible theory, something could be started off of init.rc (being how Android is based off of Linux) but I don't know enough about Android internals to judge if it launches any apps via init.rc

Comment: Possibly helpful: You can use the [Autostarts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) app to see all the different system events and what apps register for them.

Comment: @Matthew - I'm going to post a separate question about Autostarts, as a matter of fact, but just as a response to your comment, doesn't Autostarts merely list all registered Intent receivers?

Answer (score 1):

A raw native process can be created by any of the usual unix-like mechanisms.

An android activity or service is usually forked off by zygote (in response to an intent), but I think there's an obscure way to start a vm by hand using app_process.

Comment: "usual unix-like mechanisms" - could you please clarify? I'm interested specifically in what would **trigger** the start of the process (e.g. some crontab entry? process scheduler respawning recently dead processes? etc...)

Comment: Well there isn't a cron daemon on there right now, but anyone could make an unprivileged one with an ordinary app, or root and install a real one.  Ditto inetd (at least for unprivileged ports).  And yes, the framework does respawn things it doesn't think should have died.  There's really very little restriction on process creation; security is more in terms of it being quite hard to start a process as a userid that's able to do more than be obnoxious with shared resources.

Comment: could you please clarify in greater detail "the framework does re-spawn things it doesn't think should have died"? That sounds significantly closer to what I was looking for as a plausible reason why some processes keep popping up on my phone.

Comment: @DVK: in some cases background services are terminated prematurely since the foreground application needs more memory, Android may restart the service later to finish the operation.